# Minimum value in 2 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, optimization, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Find the Minimum Value of:
>   $$\frac{18}{a+b} + \frac{12}{ab} + 8a + 5b.$$

where a and b are positive real numbers

I tried evaluating the expression into 1 denominator, and tried to get squares so i can evaluate to 0 but obviously it was the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

By AM_GM we obtain:
$$\frac{18}{a+b}+\frac{12}{ab}+8a+5b=\left(\frac{18}{a+b}+2(a+b)\right)+\left(\frac{12}{ab}+6a+3b\right)\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{\frac{18}{a+b}\cdot2(a+b)}+3\sqrt[3]{\frac{12}{ab}\cdot6a\cdot3b}=30.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b)=(1,2)$, which says that $30$ is a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

[Use AM-GM by rearranging terms creatively](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#application-of-am-gm-on-terms-obtained-after-rearranging-creatively)

**Hint:** A good start of using AM-GM is to consider the following:

$ \frac{ 12}{ab} + K a + L b \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{ 12 K L }$, with equality when  $ \frac{12}{ab} = K a = Lb$.
$ \frac{18}{a+b} + M(a+b) \geq 2 \sqrt{ 18 M }$, with equality when $\frac{18}{a+b} = M (a+b)$.

Now, pick suitable $K, L, M$, so that equality holds throughout for the same values of $a, b$.

Hence, the minimum of the expression is ... which is achieved when ...

---

How to pick suitable $K, L, M$:
(I strongly encourage you to think about this before reading on. Write down whatever equations/motivations you can think of,

> We want $ K + M  = 8, L + M = 5$.
>  We wishfully think that $ 12 K L$ is a perfect cube, and $ 18 M$ is a perfect square.
>  An obvious choice is $ M = 2, K = 6, L = 3$.
>  We just need to verify that equality holds, and for the same values, which thankfully it does with $a = 1, b = 2$, giving the minimum value of 30.
>  (Otherwise, do some other wishful thinking, pick some other value of $M$ and try again.)