# Olympiad Minimization Problem

Tags: calculus, optimization, contest-math, problem-solving, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I've been struggling to find a solution to this problem that I found in the archive of my country's Olympiad questions.

I'm particularly interested in a solution that doesn't involve the use of calculus since I know that Olympiad questions do not require the knowledge of calculus to solve but I will also like to see one that uses it.

Here's the problem:

Find the minimum value of $\frac{18}{a+b} + \frac{12}{ab} + 8a + 5b$  when $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried using AM-GM to no avail. I'm just new  to solving this type of questions and I really don't know how to attack it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum value in 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493501/minimum-value-in-2-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use AM-GM by rearranging terms creatively](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#application-of-am-gm-on-terms-obtained-after-rearranging-creatively)

**Hint:** A good start of using AM-GM is to consider the following:

$ \frac{ 12}{ab} + K a + L b \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{ 12 K L }$, with equality when  $ \frac{12}{ab} = K a = Lb$.
$ \frac{18}{a+b} + M(a+b) \geq 2 \sqrt{ 18 M }$, with equality when $\frac{18}{a+b} = M (a+b)$.

Now, pick suitable $K, L, M$, so that equality holds throughout for the same values of $a, b$.

Hence, the minimum of the expression is ... which is achieved when ...

---

How to pick suitable $K, L, M$:
(I strongly encourage you to think about this before reading on. Write down whatever equations/motivations you can think of,

> We want $ K + M  = 8, L + M = 5$.
>  We wishfully think that $ 12 K L$ is a perfect cube, and $ 18 M$ is a perfect square.
>  An obvious choice is $ M = 2, K = 6, L = 3$.
>  We just need to verify that equality holds, and for the same values, which thankfully it does with $a = 1, b = 2$, giving the minimum value of 30.
>  (Otherwise, do some other wishful thinking, pick some other value of $M$ and try again.)

Comment: What made me stuck to this problem is that I looked up the answer and it turns out it's an integer. And I don't know how to bring it to that form since I always get a radical using AM-GM and the numbers do not seem to be a perfect square.

Comment: Think about what I wrote. What makes the RHS an integer? That gives us further constraints to "pick suitable K, L, M".

Comment: But how do we know that the answer is an integer?  How do we know that bringing it to an integer form minimizes the value of it?

Comment: I do not. For olympiad problems (at least for a certain difficulty), we can guess that the answer is "nice". If integers do not work, then go for radicals (IE "pick some other value of M)

Comment: Oh thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

For the calculus approach, setting the derivatives with respect to $a$ and $b$ to $0$ yields $$\frac{18}{(a + b)^2} + \frac{12}{a^2 b} = 8$$ and $$\frac{18}{(a + b)^2} 
 + \frac{12}{a b^2} = 5.$$
So 
$$\frac{12}{a^2 b} - \frac{12}{a b^2} = 3,$$
equivalently,
$$4(b - a) = a^2 b^2,$$
for which $(a,b)=(1,2)$ is an obvious solution that happens to satisfy both equations.
The second derivatives are all positive for positive $a$ and $b$.

Comment: How did you come up with this without already knowing that $ a = 1, b = 2$? With that, I can see how you grouped terms in the first step  to be 2. Otherwise, it seems magical.

Comment: Yes, the grouping was based on making each part equal to $2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin, my AM-GM argument was incomplete because the $a$ and $b$ did not cancel.  Yours is the right way.